# Serving virtual hosts with ip only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Im setting up a server locally and i want to be able to access the sites it servers without specifying a domain. If you need to know why scroll to the bottom.

I managed to serve ONE site using the IP by configuring the virtual host as such:

```
ServerName 192.168.2.10
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/public
```

This works great and all and my server can still keep on running serving in the domain based way all of the rest of the sites through their corresponding virtual hosts. The problem is, i am not sure how to go about serving MORE THAN ONE sites through the IP without using a domain.

- Maybe i could use different ports?
- Maybe theres something i can do with .htaccess and mod_rewrite that im not thinking of?

I'd be grateful if someone could lay out my options here. Thank you for taking the time.

---

*Why would i want to do this?*

First off, im curious if it can actually be done. Specifically though, as mentioned, im serving the site locally and the clients that download the app can only access it when physically present at that local network. Even though i could configure the hosts file for each of them, this sounds tedious and is in practice not feasible, especially since many of them are mobile devices and the process there is quite a ride.

Comment: DNS was invented to keep things easy and you could have defined multiple virtual hosts linked to same IP address with different ports or different IP addresses of VMs hosted on same machine with same ports. I also have came across Load Balancers who redirect traffic based on part of URLs e.g. www.example.com/siteA or www.example.com/siteB. So I am sure it can be done, but not sure of Apache way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give Apache a way to distinguish between your different sites.  Ways you can do it are:

1. DNS, domain name.  This would entail setting up VirtualHost configurations with ServerName values to match each domain.  But you do not want that, keep reading.
2. IP address.  You can have multiple addresses on your server and get Apache to Listen to each address.  Ex. Listen 1.1.1.1:80 and Listen 2.2.2.2:80.  Then each VirtualHost is configured to service one address.
3. Port.  If you can only have one IP address, you can split the site with port.  In that case you would Listen 1.1.1.1:80 and Listen 1.1.1.1:81.  Then when your clients access the sites, they would use http://1.1.1.1:80 or http://1.1.1.1:81.

Other suggestions,

- On your machine, you need to setup your IP, open your address and ports on your firewall, setup routing if required, ...
- setup each VirtualHost with separate log files, that will help a lot debug problems.
- unless the contents are the same, setup one directory per VirtualHost for your DocumentRoot.

Comment: thank you. in the meantime i figure out that ports.conf needs to be accessed to make the server listen to an extra port. i ve ended up following the ports approach. If you could add that to 3. for anyone that might be interested in this in the future it would be swell.